# LDAP - sort order of attribute's values

Tags: ldap

I got problem that when I query LDAP I get values in different order.

```
Attribute (name=cn, values={login, id, email})
Attribute (name=cn, values={id, login, email})
```

I want to force LDAP to return values in specific order, so for example login will always be in first position. Can I create LDAP query to sort values of attribute in specific order?

Answer (score 1):

The order of the return values is not part of LDAP. Some LDAP server implementations return values in a specific order (ie firstin-firstout), but LDAP does not specify.

Some LDAP Browsers will sort the values for your ([Apache Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/) does I know).